# can't we use property in the derived class out side the method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

Get error 'ClassLibrary3.Class1.a' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type' when i want to access the property of base class.

```
 namespace ClassLibrary3
    {
        public class Class1
        {
            public int a { get; set; }
            public int A { get; set; }
        }

    public class test : Class1
    {
        a=1; // error 'ClassLibrary3.Class1.a' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'
        public void hello()
        {
            a = 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; that is normal. With the exception of field initializers, the code must be in a method. That isn't a field initializer.

Either assign `a=1;` in the derived constructor, or create an overloaded constructor and pass `1` to the base type's constructor.

So either:

```
public test() {
    a = 1;
}
```

Or:

```
protected Class1(int a) {
    this.a = a;
}
...
public test() : base(1)
{}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is because `a=1` isn't in the body of a method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a to be equal to 1 when you create a test object, then you should put the a=1 into a constructor for the test class.